# Exec lines range in Maya script editor

Tags: python, range, execution, maya

It is possible to execute some lines range in a single command in Maya scripting editor? (I'm using Python)

The idea is very clear

Regularly the user needs to select some parts of the code when he/she is debugging. Let's say, for example, from line 20 to line 45 from the current tab in script editor (obviously).

The question is, the is any command like this: "execute(lines=[20,45]", or something like that.

I've been playing with "runup" and "cmdScrollFieldExecuter", but unlucky till now.

Answer (score 1):

When using Maya's script editor, you can select parts of your text and hit `Ctrl + Enter` so only this part of your script will be executed. Previously assigned variable are also still in memory.

Based on this, you can emulate this behaviour using a script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def getScriptEditor():
    for scriptEditor in cmds.lsUI( type=['cmdScrollFieldExecuter'] ):
        yield scriptEditor 

def executeLines(*args):  
    firstLine = cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_FirstLine", query=True, value=True)
    lastLine = cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_LastLine", query=True, value=True)
    scriptEditor = cmds.optionMenuGrp( "ExL_Editors", query=True, value=True)

    firstChar = None #First character to be selected as cmdScrollFieldExecuter select is made on char not lines
    lastChar = None #last character
    lineIncrement = 0 #Count line iteration

    for index, char in enumerate(cmds.cmdScrollFieldExecuter(scriptEditor, query=True, text=True)): #Iterate through all text, char by char
        if char == "\n" or index == 0: #If there is a carriage return
            lineIncrement+=1 #Increment the line number

            if lineIncrement == firstLine and not firstChar: #If this is the desired line and firstChar is still None
                firstChar = index+1 if char == "\n" else 0 #Special case for first line

            elif lineIncrement == lastLine+1 and not lastChar: #If this is the desired line and lastChar is still None
                lastChar = index

    cmds.cmdScrollFieldExecuter(scriptEditor, edit=True, select=[firstChar, lastChar]) #Select the desired range of character
    cmds.cmdScrollFieldExecuter(scriptEditor, edit=True, execute=True) #Execute them

def updateMaxValues(*args):
    scriptEditor = cmds.optionMenuGrp( "ExL_Editors", query=True, value=True)
    nbLines = cmds.cmdScrollFieldExecuter(scriptEditor, query=True, nl=True)
    cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_FirstLine", edit=True, maxValue = nbLines, fieldMaxValue=nbLines )
    cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_LastLine", edit=True, maxValue = nbLines, fieldMaxValue=nbLines )

def drawUI(*args):

    if cmds.window("Win_ExecuteLines", query=True, exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("Win_ExecuteLines")
    cmds.window( "Win_ExecuteLines", title='Execute lines of current script editor', w=390, h=50, rtf=True )
    cmds.columnLayout()

    cmds.button("ExL_RefreshButton", l="Refresh", c=drawUI, w=390)

    listEditors = getScriptEditor()
    cmds.optionMenuGrp( "ExL_Editors", l='Editors: ', cc=updateMaxValues )
    for edit in listEditors:
        cmds.menuItem( label=edit )
    cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_FirstLine", field=True, label='First Line: ', minValue=1, maxValue= 1000, fieldMinValue=1, fieldMaxValue=1000, value= 1 ) 
    cmds.intSliderGrp( "ExL_LastLine", field=True, label='Last Line: ', minValue=1, maxValue= 1000, fieldMinValue=1, fieldMaxValue=1000, value= 1 )

    cmds.button("ExL_ExecuteLines", l="Execute Lines", c=executeLines, w=390 )
    cmds.showWindow( "Win_ExecuteLines" )

drawUI()
```

The important method here is `executeLines()`, the others are only here to handle the UI but you can copy and paste this code as it is in a shelf button. This is a quick and dirty prototype of what you are looking for, so it can be greatly improved.

`executeLines()` parses the text of the selected `cmdScrollFieldExecuter` character by character. When stepping on a `\n` it check if it is the desired first or last line. It then selects the right range of characters corresponding to your specified line range and execute this code.

**Note:**

I couldn't manage to execute code from the last focused `cmdScrollFieldExecuter`, as there is only a `hasFocus` flag which is `False` for each `cmdScrollFieldExecuter` when you change the selected window (in this case, when you click on the execute button).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Python with Python source code.

Instead, split the code to functions and then call individual functions. E.g. make a function out lines 20 - 45.

Comment: Thanks Mikko, but it just with testing/debugging purposes, that's because I shouldn't split the code in individual functions.

Anyway, it was just to save some time repeating line selections.

Thanks anyway!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `exec` statement to try and execute the lines from the history that are selected.  However the utility of this is going to be extremely limited, since those lines won't do  the same thing in `exec` that they would inside a function: they won't have access to variables defined outside that selection, for example, or to all the same namespaces the original code could see.  This is really only useful in very limited situations.

You do know you can select multiple lines and `Ctrl+enter` to execute them this way, right? Subject to the same limitations as above.

Comment: Thanks for the point Theodox.

I'm afraid I can't afford a different behaviour.

Anyway, the idea was just to save some time in debugging.

Thanks anyway!.